# How to track down unknown phone Network connection to Windows 10 PC?

Tags: networking, windows-10

When viewing "Network" on my Windows 10 PC (Version 1511, OS Build 10586.679), there is one Phone device that I do not recognise:

[image: Image of unknown Phone called veniceemea in Network]

When I view its properties, this is what I see - it appears to be a Blackberry STV100-4:

[image: Picture of veniceemea properties - saying it's a Blackberry]

There are absolutely definitely no Blackberry devices here!

According to my NETGEAR VMDG485 router's Web interface, there are no devices with that MAC address connected...

**Questions**

1. Is this something I should worry about?
2. How can I track down what the device is, or troubleshoot where the connection is coming from?

Comment: You likely have networking sharing on, depending on your units network setup, it's possible your picking up your neighbors network.  Just disable network sharing

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks... Can you please clarify? Do you mean to turn off Network Discovery? I turned that off, and now nothing is shown in Network. Or do you mean [WiFi Sense - WiFi sharing](https://www.wired.com/2015/07/share-not-share-wi-fi-windows-10/) - there's no option to turn that off on my PC, as it does not have WiFi

Comment: WiFi Sense has nothing to do with network sharing l, and yes, network discovery is what I am talking about

Comment: @Ramhound OK thanks - I turned off Network Discovery and rebooted, and then nothing is shown in Network - it helpfully says "Network discovery is turned off. Network computers and devices are not visible. Click to change..." - and so I can't even see any of my own devices on my network... Which makes my PC fairly unusable on my home network....